# QComboBox drop position is moving

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I am testing some Qt code using a QComboBox.

When the QComboBox is clicked and expands, it expands out from the currently selected items position from within the list. This behaviour does not seem correct, though I have done nothing that would change the default behaviour.

So if I expand the box for the first time, is expands downwards since the first item in the box is selected. If I then select the middle item and close and open it again, when it opens it expands half upwards and half downwards. This is because the middle item is selected. If I select the bottom item, and then close and expand again, it will expand completely upwards since the selected item is in the bottom of the list of items.

I am running the application on Linux Mint 18.2. Is this just the way that QComboBoxes are designed, or is there a way I can change this behavior.

The only code at all manipulating this box is...

```
for ( QStringList::const_iterator i = colorNames.constBegin();
        i != colorNames.constEnd(); ++i ) {
    QPixmap solidPixmap( 20, 10 );
    solidPixmap.fill( QColor( *i ) );
    QIcon* solidIcon = new QIcon( solidPixmap );

    foreColorBox->addItem( *solidIcon, *i );
    backColorBox->addItem( *solidIcon, *i );
}
```

Comment: This could probably be a Linux-Mint specific behavior. On Windows-7, my QCombobox opens the selection drawer down, regardless of the selection. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPgCo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be a Linux-Mint specific behaviour. On Windows-7, my QCombobox opens the selection drawer down, regardless of the selection.

[image]

On macOS High Sierra, the same combobox has a behaviour as in your question.

[image]

So, it is evident that QCombobox implementation uses the native behaviour of the platform it runs.

Comment: I guess I have just never noticed combo box behaviour like this before.